# why do I get Not defined error when using .winfo_exists (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

.winfo_exists() is supposed to return 1 or 0 depending on the existence of a widget

when I use .winfo_exists(), to check if a widget exists then I get the error: **(Not defined)**

```
name 'ErrorLabel' not defined
```

this is how I called the function:

```
    def delete_error(self):
        if self.ErrorLabel.winfo_exists() == 1:  # even with 'self.' removed same error occurs
            self.ErrorLabel.grid_forget()
```

(above is in a class)

I tried:

- making 'self.errorlabel.winfo_exists()' into a variable and putting that in if statement
  but it didn't work

I don't understand why I get 'not defined' because I'm checking the existence of a object, so it doesn't have to be defined?

EDIT:

( the assignment of this variable depends if there is an error in input in the program so it doesn't always assign it,

that's why I need to check the existence of it when using grid_forget()

this is how it gets assigned:

```
 def raise_errors(self, flag):
    self.L5.grid_forget()
    if flag == 1 or flag == 3 or flag == 0:
        self.ErrorLabel = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Error: Fill all the blanks !", fg='white', bg='red')
        self.ErrorLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10)
    elif flag == 2:
        self.ErrorLabel = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Error: check ✔️ the correct answer ", fg='white', bg='red')
        self.ErrorLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10)
```

Comment: Can you please add the section of code where you defined `self.Errorlabel`. I think you might be misspelling the variable name/not defining it properly.

Comment: ok I edited and added the function where I assign the widget .

Comment: Do you realize `raise_errors()` have to run first, then `delete_error()`.

Comment: Yep I do realise that and 'raise error' is called first the original code, BUT the whole point is that 'raise error' assigns a widget and it will be deleted by 'delete widget'  and IF 'raise error' is not called (because there is no error) then 'delete error' checks if the widget: 'ErrorLabel' exists, to delete it. otherwise it won't need to be deleted.  ( which is why I need to check the existence of 'ErrorLabel'). . ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set `ErrorLabel` to be `None` and then check if it is `None` or not when calling `delete_error()`, if it is `None` then ignore, else find its existence.

```
def raise_errors(self, flag):
    self.ErrorLabel = None # Set to None
    self.L5.grid_forget()
    if flag == 1 or flag == 3 or flag == 0:
        self.ErrorLabel = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Error: Fill all the blanks !", fg='white', bg='red')
        self.ErrorLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10)
    elif flag == 2:
        self.ErrorLabel = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Error: check ✔️ the correct answer ", fg='white', bg='red')
        self.ErrorLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10)
```

Then your `delete_error()` would be:

```py
def delete_error(self):
    if self.ErrorLabel is not None:    
        if self.ErrorLabel.winfo_exists():
            self.ErrorLabel.grid_forget()
```

This way it checks if the widget is made and if the widget is not made, then ignores.

I don't have code here to test this with, so you should also try to define `self.ErrorLabel=None` at `__init__` too if first method doesn't work.

---

**Alternatively**, you could also use `try` and `except` to catch the error and then ignore it too:

```
def delete_error(self):
    try:
        if self.ErrorLabel.winfo_exists(): # Without setting self.ErrorLabel=None
            self.ErrorLabel.grid_forget()
    except NameError:
        pass
```