# Check if a widget exists

Tags: python, tkinter

Want to check if a button from [Tkinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) exists before I remove it.

To implement this, I wrote the following code:

```py
if btn_process.winfo_exists():
    btn_process.grid_remove()
```

When the `Button` does exist, everything works fine. But when it doesn't exist, an error message shows in the console:

> TypeError: Misc.winfo_exists() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

The code is inside a function, and I also tried to declare this button as a global variable so that it exists and put the `global btn_process` at the beginning of the function, which still doesn't work.

This error only occurs when I first check for the nonexisting button. If I create it, delete it, and delete it again, there is no error.

How can I manage this error?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Possible duplicate questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076086/see-if-tkinter-widget-exists-not-using-winfo-exists, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401167/why-do-i-get-not-defined-error-when-using-winfo-exists-tkinter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to 'fix' this error would be:

```py
try:
    # Your 'if' statement here
except TypeError:
    # An error occurred (most likely, the widget didn't exist)
```

Comment: Ignoring exceptions? It ought to be explained, including the 'why', what are the downsides, when should it be used, when should it definitely not be used, what are the consequences, include references to authoritative sources, what are some better alternatives, logging the ignored exception, naming this fishing method (change something until the symptoms go away), etc. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*.